# JPA script generation duplication statements

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA (hibernate implementation) with spring in a project. When running automated test the `persistance.xml` is configured through spring to generate the create and drop scripts for the database.

There is only one entity called `Book`. That should create one line in the create script to create the table `Book` and one line in the drop script to drop the table `Book`.

The problem is that everytime i run the tests the scripts are not regenerated but instead a new line is added to the script. So if I run the test 3 times the script looks like:

```
create table Book (title varchar(255) not null, primary key (title))
create table Book (title varchar(255) not null, primary key (title))
create table Book (title varchar(255) not null, primary key (title))
```

These are the persistance configuration values

```
    <!-- C3p0 datasource with connection pool configuration -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
</bean>

    <bean id="EntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="JpaAdapter" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="com.test.domain.PU" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="${jpa.database.action:none}"/>
            <entry key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="${jpa.scripts.action:none}"/>
            <entry key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" value="${jpa.scripts.drop-target:target/generated-resources/schemagen/db/drop.ddl}"/>
            <entry key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="${jpa.scripts.create-target:target/generated-resources/schemagen/db/create.ddl}"/>
            <!-- If present, a ddl script is loaded to init the db. Used only during development. For production a specific script will be provided. 
                 The script is activated on create, drop-and-create, and create-and-drop options for database schema creation -->                    
            <entry key="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="${jpa.sql-load-script-source:sql/init_db.ddl}"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And the property files used during the test is:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=

jdbc.showSql=true
jpa.database.action=drop-and-create
jpa.scripts.action=drop-and-create
```

Does somebody knows what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Did you try put @Transactional over main method?

Comment: I am using @Transactional over the main method. After further investigation it seems to be an issue with the hibernate version.

Answer (score 2):

After some further investigation it seems that the issue is related to hibernate.

I am using version 5.2.10.Final of hibernate. However, when i switch back to version 4.3.6.Final of hibernate everything works fine.